# Best way to add git to existing project

Tags: git, deployment, version-control

We inherited a site with zero version control / no info on how it was built - only enough info to ssh onto the server. We want to add git, so we can start developing locally and pushing updates via git.

What's the best way to do this, without breaking anything?

My first inclination is to create a blank repo on github, initialize a git repo inside the site root (which I'm 99% sure about..), `git add .`, `git commit -m "Initial commit"` and push everything to github. Then clone the repo and create a staging and local site.

I just want to double confirm that is a sound plan, because I don't do this very often (usually start off projects with git from the very beginning). And I don't want to break anything while I'm poking around on the server.

Thank you :)

Comment: What you've said will do. I personally add a blank commit before any source code by using `git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial commit"`

Comment: you don't need the detour through github, cloning directly does work, but yes, what you plan works. Often, you *can* identify things that shouldn't be tracked in git directly, for example folders called `.cache` or pre-compiled script files. having a `.gitignore` from https://gitignore.io in your project's root directory before doing the first `git commit` might be a good idea, if you know the languages used. You can also look for which files have recently been modified – chances are, they are not part of the original source code but added by the software later on and shouldn't be tracked.

Comment: I agree with @MarcusMüller. I wouldn't add the entire project including all the binaries into the first commit. At least not in the "final" version of the repo. You could include them for now, and once you figure out how to build it and get your `.gitignore` file working properly, you can then either rewrite the repo to remove the binaries (from all commits using `git-filter-repo`), or just create a new repo from scratch later.

Comment: I was about to write my point of view but @TTT comment sum it perfectly. **In your specific case**, I highly recommend you to follow it to ensure you have a perfect backup and take the time to craft the good '.gitignore'. Then rewrite the history in another branch. If you don't really have space problem, keep the original branch as a backup as long as you are 100% confident on the cleaning. In the end (maybe after multiple new releases), you will be able to delete the original branch and free space.

Answer (score 1):

In such situation I use the following checklist:

```
 1. git init
 2. git remote add origin <REMOTE-REPO-URL>
 3. Write a good '.gitignore` file.
 4. git add --all
 5. git commit -m "Initial commit"
 6. git push
```

Comment: agreed. As mentioned above, I usually use https://gitignore.io to get a starting point for a  .gitignore file, and then refine. The nice thing is that using `git status` I can see which files *would* be added if I did `git add` with the current .gitignore.

Comment: Oh yeah I almost forgot about .gitignore - glad I brought it up! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: step three is " `git ls-files --other --exclude standard`. Add patterns to `.gitignore` until that lists all and only the paths you want tracked."